# How to generate OAuth1 HMAC SHA1 signature in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, swift3

I'm working on a small swift program to work with Yelp API over OAuth-1. I am looking to generate a HMAC-SHA1 signature.

I have the customer key, secret key , token and token secret.

From what I know, to make an API request with `OAuth1`, we need the following attributes :

1. 1.oauth_consumer_key
2. oauth_token
3. oauth_signature_method = (HMAC-SHA1)
4. oauth_signature
5. oauth_timestamp
6. oauth_nonce

I have the first `1,2,3` parts but I don't know how do I generate `#4,5,6`
I am kind of new to ios/swift3 so please point me into right direction

Comment: Did you get your solution?

Comment: Did you get your solution?

Answer (score 0):

try to look at that implementation: https://github.com/SwiftP2P/SwiftSSL/blob/master/SwiftSSL/HMAC.swift